# Light switch with no ground wire attached

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I am trying to install a new switch but the ground wire was never attached to the old switch and this is what I have, any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is that back-box plastic or metal? Does the switch itself have an earth tab?

Comment: The 2 copper wires wound together that I *believe* to be the grounds run up in to the wall so I cannot see. And the box is plastic.

Comment: Of course they run into the wall, that's how they get to earth. If it's a plastic box, then they should connect to the switch itself - which they currently don't. Does the switch have an earth tab?

Comment: Can just use a wirenut and pigtail on a piece of ground wire to new switch.  Be careful that the bare grounds do not contact any hot/live screws/wire on the switch.

Comment: Yes sir it does, but nothing connected to it.

Comment: Then you need, as @crip659 mentions, to extend the wire to reach. Personally, I'd make sure it's properly sheathed too, but that's UK code, doesn't seem to be US.

Comment: US/CAN we use bare or green insulated wire for ground.  If insulated must be green or green plus colour for ground.

Answer (score 1):

If your new switch has a ground wire attached to it, wire nut that ground wire to the two twisted ground wires in the junction box. If the new switch doesn't have a ground wire but does have a green grounding screw, get a 6" piece of bare copper or green insulated wire and connect one end to the switch grounding screw and wire nut the other end to the ground wires in the box. If the new switch has neither of these grounding methods, then the switch doesn't need to be grounded.